# Set Windows Django Project Folder To OS-X/Linux Style

Tags: django, apache, bitnami

In when adding a Django project to Bitnami on OS-X, the path to the projects is

`"*installdir*\apps\django\django_projects"` ( in the install directory)

When in windows it is

`"C:\Users\*USER*\Bitnami DjangoStack Projects"` (outside the install directory)

I'm on windows 7 and would like to configure Bitnami to use the OS-X style folder where it is all contained within the install directory rather than being in a separate folder.

If this is a possibility, how would I go about doing this?

*EDIT*

would there be another Stack Site better suited for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try copying the project folder to installdir and change the path in the following files:

```
installdir\apache2\conf\bitnami\bitnami-apps-prefix.conf
installdir\Bitnami DjangoStack Projects\conf\httpd-prefix.conf
installdir\Bitnami DjangoStack Projects\conf\httpd-app.conf
installdir\Bitnami DjangoStack Projects\project\wsgi.py
```

And then restart the application?